# VBA Button to Clear a Range of Cells

Tags: vba, excel

As the title states, I am trying to create a button to clear a range of cells. Prior to clearing the cells, I have a dialog box pop up to confirm the selection. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If MsgBox("THIS WILL CLEAR EVERYTHING IN THE CART! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    Range("A28:AA47").ClearContents

End Sub
```

The code works when I'm in Design Mode and press "Play" but the button won't work on my sheet when I'm out of Design Mode.

Is the code completely ending itself when I select "No", to the point where it will not run again even if I hit the button again?

Comment: The code works fine for me. Is the button on the same sheet you're clearing? Have you actually deselected the design mode? Do you get the pop up box confirmation at all?

Comment: Having the code window closed is not the same as being out of design mode... if you're clicking the Button and it's just selecting the outside of it (like to resize etc.) then you're still in design mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a little incomplete. Try this instead:

EDIT: Cleaned it up a little more. No need for a `vbNo`, as if you don't select yes, the subroutine will simply end.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If MsgBox("THIS WILL CLEAR EVERYTHING IN THE CART! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Range("A28:AA47").ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This cleaned it up. I also found that I had multiple buttons and had the code running under the wrong button. Everything is working now, thank you!